# Using PHP to display a tree structure pulled from a database

Tags: php, recursion, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a database table with these records:

```
parent_id   child_id    
    0   1   
    0   2   
    0   3   
    0   4   
    0   5   
    0   6   
    0   7   
    0   8   
    0   9   
    0   10  
    0   11  
    0   12  
    1   13  
    1   14  
    1   15  
    2   16  
    2   17  
    2   18  
    3   19  
    3   20  
    3   21  
    4   22  
    4   23  
    4   24  
    5   25  
    5   26  
    5   27  
    6   28  
    6   29  
    6   30  
    7   31  
    7   32  
    7   33  
    7   34  
    1   35  
    1   36  
    1   37  
    1   38  
    1   39
```

I want to build a tree structure with parent/child using a recursive function.

```
function recursion ($parentID, $lvl){

$query = 'SELECT parent_id, child_id FROM ///// WHERE parent_id='.$parentID;    
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
$this->_db->query();
$records = $this->_db->loadObjectList();

$count = count($records);

    if ($count > 0){
            foreach ($records as $item){
                print_r ("parent id  ".$item->parent_id."child id  ".$item->child_id."  lvl->  ".$lvl."</br>");
                return $this->recursion($item->child_id, $lvl+1);
        }
    }
}
```

My code only prints:

```
parent id 0child id 1 lvl-> 1
parent id 1child id 13 lvl-> 2
```

I can't figure out how to print the whole tree. I guess I'm on the right path. Can someone give me a hint on how to print the whole tree?

Comment: Raim, usually it is good practice to tag a question with the language you are using. This allows people to spot which questions they might be able to answer.

Comment: Not the way you're doing it, but maybe this helps you: http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/317/formatting-a-multi-level-menu-using-only-one-query.html -- An easy and short tutorial on how to build such a tree view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **return**.

Next time take a piece of paper, and walk through the code, line by line. Write down what will happen. Think about it.

Now if you want to impress your teacher, figure out how to do this *without* recursion. Most recursion functions can be made procedural, and it uses less memory.

Comment: Thanks you very mutch for your answers. Glad there is someone who helps :) Removing Return solved my problem, and now its printing all parents,then theyr children, and if children have children them too. Have a nice day Gustav Bertram, thanks you again :)

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can **accept** the answer. See the FAQ to find out how: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

1. if you want to print out whole tree do not use recursion.
2. make right ONE SQL query, and then make right output what you need.
3. If you will tell more about what you want to get, it can make easier to help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thats is the point, i have task from my teacher to do it with recursion. yesterday he said that I am on the right way. As you can see, my code goes through records, first variable is 0, so its start at the parent 0, then it takes thats parents child ( 1 ), then it returns childs value as parents and search db with that value, returns 1, 13 - level is going up, and again, now search goes with 13 as parent, and then it stops. I want to keep it going through all DB. If its get in dead end (like now), i want it to return to previous level, and do it all over again, till all DB is checked.